# No letters of certain fonts using winfonts package

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I am trying to use the `winfonts` package on Windows 8. I installed according to instructions—copied them to texmf-local, edited local config files, update the file names and map files. When I compile this test file under pdflatex,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{winfonts}
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{georgia}\selectfont
abcdefg

\fontfamily{arial}\selectfont
abcdefg

\fontfamily{times-ttf}\selectfont
abcdefg

\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont
abcdefg

\fontfamily{franklingothic}\selectfont
abcdefg

\fontfamily{impact}\selectfont
abcdefg
\end{document}
```

three of the fonts display correctly (Georgia, Franklin Gothic and Impact) while the other three are displayed only as ▯▯▯▯▯▯. What is the cause of this?

I'm using TeXLive 2012, last updated on 2012-12-26.

---

The log file is very long, but there is something interesting

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/Windows/fonts/verdana.ttf): glyph `a' not found
```

Comment: Show the log-file.

Comment: An alternative would be to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and use `fontspec` to load systems fonts.

Comment: @Guido: I know that. But pdflatex is much faster. This is not an urgent matter, but it would be better to have a faster compilation.

Comment: This probably means that your verdana.ttf version doesn't contains glyph names and you will need (at least) an .enc file which uses the `uniXXXX` notation. See http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb30-1/tb94thanh.pdf. (I can't make tests, I don't have windows8 and it works fine with my version of the fonts.)

Comment: C. R. Do you already solve this problem with winfonts package on windows 8 ? I have the same problem. Can you help me?